# convolution product of $n$ same distribution

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, convolution

I tried to solve this problem,

Let $K\in L_{loc}^{\infty}$, for $n\in N$, we note $K_{n} = K*K*K...*K$ ($n$ factors), show for every $a > 0$, for every $x \in [0, a]$ and for every $n \in N$ that:

$$
|K_{n}(x)| \le (\sup_{x \in [0, a]}(|K(x)|))^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$

but i don't know where to start. (i tried recurrence by i stuck to prove it for $n+1$)

the problem is long if anyone have any reference to complete solution of this problem this will be a big help.

thanks

Edit:

I think we can solve it like that:

for $n = 1$ it's clear that $|K(x)| \le (\sup_{x \in [0, a]}(|K(x)|))$

for $n = 2$ we have
$$
|K_{2}(x)| = \left| \int^{x}_{0}K(x-t)K(t)dt \right| \le (\sup_{x \in [0, a]}(|K(x)|))^2\times x
$$
because $ 0 \le x -t \le a$ and $ t \ge 0$

for $n \ge 2$ we have
$$
|K_{n}(x)| = \left| 
\int^{x}_{0}K(x-t_1)
\left(\int^{t_1}_{0}K(t_1-t_2) \dots \left(\int^{t_{n-2}}_{0}K(t_{n-2}-t_{n-1})K(t_{n-1})  dt_{n-1}\right) \dots  dt_2\right) 
dt_1 \right| \le (\sup_{x \in [0, a]}(|K(x)|))^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$

Comment: Maybe consider the Fourier transform of $K_n$? In that case the convolution theorem tells you that the result is the $n$th power of the Fourier transform of $K$.

Comment: Is $L^\infty_{loc}$ supposed to mean $L^\infty_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ or maybe $L^\infty_{loc}((0,\infty))$ or what? It makes a big difference...

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, the problem don't tell us anything. how to solve it if we suppose $L_{loc}^{\infty}((0, \infty))$?